# You use Rolle's theorem to prove n-polynomial has n distinct roots, but how would you do this question?

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if a polynomial of degree n has n real roots (which don't have to be distinct) then its derivative has n-1 real roots (which also don't have to be distinct).

Comment: Rolle gives you that between two roots of a function, there is a root of its derivative.

Comment: Hint: if the roots are $x_1,\ldots,x_{n}$, try to apply $n-1$ times Rolle in intervals $(x_i,x_{i+1})$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n-1$

Comment: In the case that the polynomial has a root of multiplicity $m$, show that it's a root of the derivative of multiplicity $m-1$.  Combining this with the above comments should give you a path to the proof.

Comment: Hint: if there are at most $n-2$ real roots of the derivative, how many real roots can the polynomial have? Do the distinct case first and then analyse what may happen with multiple roots.

Comment: It is actually easier and more intuitive to prove the complex version of the statement. Take a look at [Gauss-Lucas theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem), you can easily adopt the proof there to real case.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the distinct roots $s_1,s_2,\ldots s_{\ell}$ with respective multiplicities $b_1,b_2,\ldots b_{\ell}$. Now see that $b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_{\ell}=n$ now the $\ell$ distinct roots give $\ell-1$ roots of the derivative and the multiplicities contribute $b_i-1$ each. Adding them up we get $\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\ell}b_i\right)+\ell-1=n-1$ roots.
$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply *Rolle's Theorem* between all the roots of $p(x)$. As to be clearer, apply it in $[x_1,x_2], [x_2,x_3], [x_3,x_3] ... $ and so on (until $[x_{n-1},x_n]$). Then you'll find a real number inside all the intervals such that its derivative equals zero. Now, how many intervals are there? $n-1$ $\Rightarrow$ there are $n-1$ real roots of the derivative $p'(x)$

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $p(x)$ is a polynomial with $n$ ordered real roots, $a_1 \leq ...,\leq a_n$.  Then since $p$ is continuous on $[a_1, a_2]$, differentiable on $(a_1, a_2)$, and $p(a_1) = p(a_2)$ we can apply Rolle's theorem to conclude that there exists a real number, $c_1 \in (a_1, a_2)$ such that $f^\prime(c_1) = 0$.  Repeat this argument for the $n-2$ remaining intervals $(a_j, a_{j+1})$.

Comment: Say one of the real roots had a multiplicity of more than one, say.  How would that be factored into this proof?

Comment: Well the problem you have here says that they may not be distinct so it only works when the roots are distinct otherwise you undercount in a large amount. Exactly what mvgwpemb tried to say.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my proof is valid only if the roots are distinct.